# How to parse a CSV in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, csv, shell

I am trying to parse a CSV containing potentially 100k+ lines. Here is the criteria I have:

1. The index of the identifier
2. The identifier value

I would like to retrieve all lines in the CSV that have the given value in the given index (delimited by commas).

Any ideas, taking in special consideration for performance?

Comment: For a robust awk solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned `csvcut`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First prototype using plain old `grep` and `cut`:

```
grep "${VALUE}" inputfile.csv | cut -d, -f"${INDEX}"
```

If that's fast enough and gives the proper output, you're done.

Comment: +1. This pipeline doesn't allow colon escaping (`\:`) or string quoting (`"foo: bar"`). But it is a good and simple way of solving the problem.

Comment: there's no need to use 2 tools across a pipe. I would recommend using awk.

Comment: @ghostdog: I don't know awk, and looking at e.g. Nate Kohl's awk reply, I think this qualifies as being simpler, at least.

Comment: Although the answer is correct for some CSV files, imho it's more damaging than helping, because it encourages people on SO to prefer "one liner" commands and happily adopt them without realizing the problems associated with those (which the answer didn't warn about as well). In short, you parse a certain file format with a specific file format parser. Just like you don't use regex to validate html, but instead you use an html parser/validator. The fact that such "one-liners" work for some special cases of those file formats should be in bold/underline letters, always.

Answer (score 61):

As an alternative to `cut`- or `awk`-based one-liners, you could use the specialized [`csvtool`](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-csv) aka `ocaml-csv`:

```
$ csvtool -t ',' col "$index" - < csvfile | grep "$value"
```

According to the docs, it handles escaping, quoting, etc.

Comment: I think csvtool is my new best friend.  Crazy to think I was trying to parse .csv files in bash.  Replaced a large number of bash lines to handle parsing and escaping quotes, embedded commas, etc with a single call to csvtool!

Comment: Awesome solution, but requires the user has `csvtool` installed. This can be a problem when you need to use standard tools.

Comment: To get this thing: `sudo apt-get install csvtool`  on ubuntu etc... then `csvtool --help` as the man page is, erm, sparse.

Answer (score 43):

See this youtube video: [BASH scripting lesson 10 working with CSV files](http://youtu.be/OecFFZpIkDc)

CSV file:

```
Bob Brown;Manager;16581;Main
Sally Seaforth;Director;4678;HOME
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=";"
while read user job uid location
 do

    echo -e "$user \
    ======================\n\
    Role :\t $job\n\
    ID :\t $uid\n\
    SITE :\t $location\n"
 done < $1
 IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Output:

```
Bob Brown     ======================
    Role :   Manager
    ID :     16581
    SITE :   Main

Sally Seaforth     ======================
    Role :   Director
    ID :     4678
    SITE :   HOME
```

Comment: This looks as it doesn't handle quoted values correctly (like `"Bob Brown";"Manager";16581;"Main"` or even `"Bob Brown";"Manager; Director";16581;"Main"`)

Comment: This answer doesn't fit the parameters of the original question, using a specific value and column index number.

Comment: This answer also fails on lines ending in backslash characters (as I just learned)

Answer (score 14):

CSV isn't quite that simple. Depending on the limits of the data you have, you might have to worry about quoted values (which may contain commas and newlines) and escaping quotes.

So if your data are restricted enough can get away with simple comma-splitting fine, shell script can do that easily. If, on the other hand, you need to parse CSV ‘properly’, bash would not be my first choice. Instead I'd look at a higher-level scripting language, for example Python with a [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 11):

In a CSV file, each field is separated by a comma. The problem is, a field itself might have an embedded comma:

```
Name,Phone
"Woo, John",425-555-1212
```

You really need a library package that offer robust CSV support instead of relying on using comma as a field separator. I know that scripting languages such as Python has such support. However, I am comfortable with the Tcl scripting language so that is what I use. Here is a simple Tcl script which does what you are asking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

package require csv 
package require Tclx

# Parse the command line parameters
lassign $argv fileName columnNumber expectedValue

# Subtract 1 from columnNumber because Tcl's list index starts with a
# zero instead of a one
incr columnNumber -1

for_file line $fileName {
    set columns [csv::split $line]
    set columnValue [lindex $columns $columnNumber]
    if {$columnValue == $expectedValue} {
        puts $line
    }   
}
```

Save this script to a file called csv.tcl and invoke it as:

```
$ tclsh csv.tcl filename indexNumber expectedValue
```

## Explanation

The script reads the CSV file line by line and store the line in the variable $line, then it split each line into a list of columns (variable $columns). Next, it picks out the specified column and assigned it to the $columnValue variable. If there is a match, print out the original line.

Answer (score 9):

Using `awk`:

```
export INDEX=2
export VALUE=bar

awk -F, '$'$INDEX' ~ /^'$VALUE'$/ {print}' inputfile.csv
```

**Edit:** As per [Dennis Williamson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson) excellent comment, this could be much more cleanly (and safely) written by defining awk variables using the `-v` switch:

```
awk -F, -v index=$INDEX -v value=$VALUE '$index == value {print}' inputfile.csv
```

Jeez...with variables, and everything, awk is almost [a real programming language](https://web.archive.org/web/20131001161157/http://oreilly.com/catalog/unixnut3/chapter/ch11.html)...

Comment: The exports are likely unnecessary. And you should use `awk's` variable-passing feature, otherwise the quoting can get hairy: `awk -F, -v index=$INDEX -v value=$VALUE '$index == value {print}' inputfile.csv`

Comment: This doesn't handle nontrivial CSV files with quoted fields which might contain newlines.

Answer (score 5):

For situations where the data does not contain any special characters, the solution suggested by Nate Kohl and ghostdog74 is good.

If the data contains commas or newlines inside the fields, awk may not properly count the field numbers and you'll get incorrect results.

You can still use awk, with some help from a program I wrote called csvquote (available at https://github.com/dbro/csvquote):

```
csvquote inputfile.csv | awk -F, -v index=$INDEX -v value=$VALUE '$index == value {print}' | csvquote -u
```

This program finds special characters inside quoted fields, and temporarily replaces them with nonprinting characters which won't confuse awk. Then they get restored after awk is done.

Answer (score 3):

```
index=1
value=2
awk -F"," -v i=$index -v v=$value '$(i)==v' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for an elegant solution that support quoting and wouldn't require installing anything fancy on my VMware vMA appliance. Turns out this simple python script does the trick! (I named the script `csv2tsv.py`, since it converts CSV into tab-separated values - TSV)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, csv

with sys.stdin as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for col in row:
            print col+'\t',
        print
```

Tab-separated values can be split easily with the cut command (no delimiter needs to be specified, tab is the default). Here's a sample usage/output:

```
> esxcli -h $VI_HOST --formatter=csv network vswitch standard list |csv2tsv.py|cut -f12
Uplinks
vmnic4,vmnic0,
vmnic5,vmnic1,
vmnic6,vmnic2,
```

In my scripts I'm actually going to parse tsv output line by line and use read or cut to get the fields I need.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing CSV with primitive text-processing tools will fail on many types of CSV input.

[xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) is a lovely and *fast* tool for doing this properly. To search for all records that contain the string "foo" in the third column:

```
cat file.csv | xsv search -s 3 foo
```

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` or `awk` solution would probably be shorter, but here's one for Perl:

```
perl -F/,/ -ane 'print if $F[<INDEX>] eq "<VALUE>"`
```

where `<INDEX>` is 0-based (0 for first column, 1 for 2nd column, etc.)

Comment: If you're going to use perl anyhow, surely there a perl csv library that would be better to use?

Comment: For well-behaved input? [That's not true.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916962/fastest-csv-parser-in-perl/13917440)

Comment: @mob Better doesn't always mean faster.

Answer (score 0):

Awk (gawk) actually provides extensions, one of which being [csv processing](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/csv/gawk-csv.html).

Assuming that extension is installed, you can use awk to show all lines where a specific csv field matches `123`.

Assuming `test.csv` contains the following:

```
Name,Phone
"Woo, John",425-555-1212
"James T. Kirk",123
```

The following will print all lines where the `Phone` (aka the second field) is equal to `123`:

```bash
gawk -l csv 'csvsplit($0,a) && a[2] == 123 {print $0}'
```

The output is:

```
"James T. Kirk",123
```

How does it work?

- `-l csv` asks gawk to load the `csv` extension by looking for it in `$AWKLIBPATH`;
- `csvsplit($0, a)` splits the current line, and stores each field into a new array named `a`
- `&& a[2] == 123` checks that the second field is `123`
- if both conditions are true, it `{ print $0 }`, aka prints the full line as requested.

Answer (score 0):

**ask `FPAT`**

This optoin is worth knowing about this if you ever need to customize the parsing a bit. Unfortunately it can't handle quoted newlines. Demo adapted from [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk/45420607#45420607)

```
echo 'foo,"field,""with"",commas",bar' |
  awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) print i " <" $i ">"}' \
    FPAT='[^,]*|("([^"]|"")*")'
1 <foo>
2 <"field,""with"",commas">
3 <bar>
```