# Fastest CSV Parser in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, csv

I am creating a subroutine that:

(1) Parses a CSV file;

(2) And checks if all the rows in that file have the expected number of columns. It croaks if the number of columns is invalid.

When the number of rows is ranging from thousands to millions, **what do you think is the *most efficient* way to do it?**

Right now, I'm trying out these implementations.

**(1) Basic file parser**

```
open my $in_fh, '<', $file or 
    croak "Cannot open '$file': $OS_ERROR";                                                            
                                                                                                      
my $row_no = 0;                                                                                           
while ( my $row = <$in_fh> ) {                                                                            
    my @values = split (q{,}, $row);                                                                      
    ++$row_no;                                                                                            
    if ( scalar @values < $min_cols_no ) {                                                                
        croak "Invalid file format. File '$file' does not have '$min_cols_no' columns in line '$row_no'.";
    }                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                         
                                                                                                      
close $in_fh                                                                                              
    or croak "Cannot close '$file': $OS_ERROR";
```

**(2) Using Text::CSV_XS (bind_columns and csv->getline)**

```
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new () or                                                                         
   croak "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV_XS->error_diag();                                                 
open my $in_fh, '<', $file or                                                                             
   croak "Cannot open '$file': $OS_ERROR";                                                                
                                                                                                          
 my $row_no = 1;                                                                                          
 my @cols = @{$csv->getline($in_fh)};                                                                     
 my $row = {};                                                                                            
 $csv->bind_columns (\@{$row}{@cols});                                                                    
 while ($csv->getline ($in_fh)) {                                                                         
    ++$row_no;                                                                                            
    if ( scalar keys %$row < $min_cols_no ) {                                                             
        croak "Invalid file format. File '$file' does not have '$min_cols_no' columns in line '$row_no'.";
    }                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                         
                                                                                                          
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();                                                                          
close $in_fh or
    croak "Cannot close '$file': $OS_ERROR";
```

**(3) Using Text::CSV_XS (csv->parse)**

```
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new() or                                                                         
   croak "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV_XS->error_diag();                                                
 open my $in_fh, '<', $file or                                                                           
   croak "Cannot open '$file': $OS_ERROR";                                                               
                                                                                                         
 my $row_no = 0;                                                                                         
 while ( <$in_fh> ) {                                                                                    
     $csv->parse($_);                                                                                    
     ++$row_no;                                                                                          
     if ( scalar $csv->fields < $min_cols_no ) {                                                         
       croak "Invalid file format. File '$file' does not have '$min_cols_no' columns in line '$row_no'.";
     }                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                        
                                                                                                         
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();                                                                         
close $in_fh or 
    croak "Cannot close '$file': $OS_ERROR";
```

**(4) Using Parse::CSV**

```
use Parse::CSV;                                                                                           
my $simple = Parse::CSV->new(                                                                             
    file => $file                                                                                         
);                                                                                                        
                                                                                                          
my $row_no = 0;                                                                                           
while ( my $array_ref = $simple->fetch ) {                                                                
    ++$row_no;                                                                                            
    if ( scalar @$array_ref < $min_cols_no ) {                                                            
        croak "Invalid file format. File '$file' does not have '$min_cols_no' columns in line '$row_no'.";
    }                                                                                                     
}
```

I benchmark-ed them using the Benchmark module.

```
use Benchmark qw(timeit timestr timediff :hireswallclock);
```

And these are the **numbers (in seconds)** that I got:

**1,000 lines of file:**

> Implementation 1: 0.0016
>
> Implementation 2: 0.0025
>
> Implementation 3: 0.0050
>
> Implementation 4: 0.0097

**10,000 lines of file:**

> Implementation 1: 0.0204
>
> Implementation 2: 0.0244
>
> Implementation 3: 0.0523
>
> Implementation 4: 0.1050

**1,500,000 lines of file:**

> Implementation 1: 1.8697
>
> Implementation 2: 3.1913
>
> Implementation 3: 7.8475
>
> Implementation 4: 15.6274

Given these numbers, I would conclude that the simple parser is the fastest but from what I have read from different sources, Text::CSV_XS should be the fastest.

Will someone enlighten me on this? Is there something wrong with how I used the modules? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why is speed so important to you?  Are you sure that it is the slow spot of your code?  Is your program speed even a problem?  Are you sure you're not prematurely optimizing?  If, for example, your program spends 90% of the time writing to the database, and 10% reading from the CSV file, then finding the fastest CSV parser is not the best way to spend your time.

Comment: `'"That's the thing about strings", he said, "you can include commas, periods, and all other kinds of stuff in quotes!"'`

Comment: @AndyLester, speed is so important since this is an added functionality or step to the current workflow of almost all the systems that we have, and we don't want to add any additional time if possible. In this case, I would really like to learn from the experts if I was doing it the right way or not. I would also agree with you. It really makes a lot more sense to optimize the writing to the database since most of the time, the bottleneck happens there. FYI, we're using freebcp for inserting. Thanks again, Andy!

Comment: @JackManey, I googled parts of those statements but couldn't find the source. Where did you get that? Thanks too!

Comment: @Carlisle: I understand that you "don't want to add any additional time if possible."  Nobody does.  But realistically, it's a matter of what "any additional time" means.  If you have something that runs in 37 minutes before any changes, and in 37:02 when you use Text::CSV::Whatever, then does it matter if there's something that could make it run in 37:01?  Is it worth expensive programmer time figuring that out? Or maybe using a module that requires you to write code that is less understandable? And of course, you can't answer any of that without measurements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that your `Text::CSV_XS` version does more than your simple parser version.  It splits the line, puts it into memory, and makes your hashref point to the fields.

It also may have other logic under the hood, like allowing escaped delimiters (I don't know, as I haven't used it).  On top of that, there is always a small amount of overhead when using a module: function calls, passing parameters back and forth, and perhaps generic code that doesn't really apply in your case (such as error checking for things you don't care about).

Normally the benefits of using a module greatly outweigh the costs.  You get more features, more reliable code, etc.  But that might not be true with a small, very simple task.  If all you need to do is verify the number of columns, using a module might be overkill.  You could make your own implementation even faster by just counting the number of columns,  and not bothering to split at all:

```
/(?:,[^,]*){$min_cols_no-1}/ or croak "Did not find minimum number of columns";
```

If you are going to do real processing in addition to this verification step, using the module will probably be beneficial.

Answer (score 19):

There are CSV files

```
header1,header2,header3
value1,value2,value3
```

and then there are CSV files.

```
header1,"This, as they say, is header2","And header3
even contains a newline!"
value1,"value2, 2nd in a series of 3 values",value3
```

`Text::CSV` and its ilk have been painstakingly developed and tested to deal with the second kind. If you are confident that your input does and always will conform to the simple CSV specification, then it is very likely that you can build a parser that will outperform `Text::CSV`.

Comment: I understand it more now. Thanks, @mob!

Answer (score 1):

All CSV parsing modules do the same thing: opening the file and parse the CSV in some way, much like you did in your basic sub. They just carry a lot more overhead because internally, they do a lot more than you need (check for proper CSV format, pass around object structures etc). That makes them slower than your basic approach, to varying extent.

You benchmarked the approaches yourself; isn't the result obvious? If I didn't need the extended functionality of the CSV modules, I would parse a CSV file the basic way myself.

(I don't know if you could speed them up by improving your usage of the modules)

Comment: I would like to confirm that my approach was right, and I'm not missing anything here. Now, I really learn that, like what @dan1111 said, "normally the benefits of using a module greatly outweigh the costs." Thanks too!

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I tested regexp for this... and it works! ;) If you have enough of ram, you can read whole file at once, and next use regular expression:

```
my $blob = 'a;s;d
q;w;e
r;t;y
u;i;o
p;z;x
c;;b
n;m;f
g;h;j
k;l;';

say $blob =~ /^ ([^;]*;){2}[^;]* (\n (([^;]*;){2}[^;]*)+ \n ([^;]*;){2}[^;]*)? $/x ? 'ok' : 'bu';
```

But this doesn't include delimiter escaping, quoting etc - just test for specified quantity of delimiters :)