# Using grep with cut in Bash

Tags: bash, csv

I'm trying to go through a CSV file (technically a .gz file) and read the second column. Came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560393/bash-shell-scripting-csv-parsing) but am having some difficulty with using the first answer.

Command I'm using is `grep ${VALUE} inputfile.csv | cut -d, -f${INDEX}`.

For my shell script, I think it should be `grep ${apples} inputfile.csv | cut -d, -f${2}`.

However, I'm getting an error of

```
cut: option requires an argument -- 'f'
Try 'cut --help' for more information
```

The comma in the command didn't seem right, so I edited it to

`grep ${apples} inputfile.csv | cut -d -f${INDEX}`

which gave me an error of

```
The delimiter must be a single character
Try 'cut --help' for more information
```

What is the right syntax for grabbing the field after apples? CSV file header looks like this - very simple:

fruits | fruitcount

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question you linked used variables to show where you would place the values you want to use, you don't need the `${}` syntax:

```
grep apples inputfile.csv | cut -d, -f2
```

Comment: `VALUE` could contain spaces, so `"$VALUE"` is better (or `"${VALUE}"` if your prefer – I don't.)

Comment: I don't prefer it, but would like to keep it consistent with the referenced question & answer. I've updated to wrap `VALUE` in quotes.

Comment: Is the double quotes around `"${VALUE}"` to search exact string?

Comment: @simplycoding, it is for the case that `VALUE="apples and pears"`. Without quotes, `grep` would see four arguments instead of two

Comment: You don't need to `export` those variables

Comment: My most recent edit addresses all of these comments.

Comment: Would anyone know how to cast the output of the line into an integer? I can't seem to do any arithmetic functions on it

Comment: @simplycoding I would suggest opening another question

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently can be replaced with this awk script

```
awk -F, '/apples/{print $2}' inputfile.csv
```