# Count of Indexes for each collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, count

I want to Count() indexes for each collection which collection name start with specific name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this part of the [Mongo Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/). Below a part of the documentation.

**List all Indexes on a Collection**

To return a list of all indexes on a collection, use the db.collection.getIndexes() method or a similar method for your driver.

For example, to view all indexes on the people collection:

```
db.people.getIndexes()
```

**List all Indexes for a Database**

To list all indexes on all collections in a database, you can use the following operation in the mongo shell:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
   indexes = db[collection].getIndexes();
   print("Indexes for " + collection + ":");
   printjson(indexes);
});
```

to limit, you could do something like:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
   if (collection.indexOf("%YOU SEARCH STRING HERE%") > -1){
      indexes = db[collection].getIndexes();
      print("Indexes for " + collection + ":");
      printjson(indexes);
   }
});
```

And now with count

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
   if (collection.indexOf("%YOU SEARCH STRING HERE%") > -1){
      indexes = db[collection].getIndexes();
      print("Indexes for " + collection + ":");
      print(indexes.length);
   }
});
```

And with index names

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
   if (collection.indexOf("valueblue") > -1){
      indexes = db[collection].getIndexes();
      print("Indexes for " + collection + ":");
      print(indexes.length);

      indexes.forEach(function(item){
        print(item.name);
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: this i will get all collection indexes but i want count of that and for each collection ..

Comment: i have 1000 of collections and i want to get count of those collection indexes which start with specific name.So here i need to use ;
----regex for specific collection name
----Indexes Count
-----separately count of indexes for those collections.
need help ?
need to write some Script or what ?

Comment: Then use the 2nd example and add a filter inside the foreach, which "tests" the collection name.

Comment: @NehaB added an xtra sample

Comment: still i am struggling with the query.i want count of indexes for each collection ??help me out?

Comment: @NehaB I added an extra sample which filters the collections, it will only do the count on the collection matching your search string. I don't know what problem you are facing now..

Comment: i run that query but nothing is happing with that query.i m not getting any result.

Comment: You need to replace %YOU SEARCH STRING HERE% with the collection value you want... ex. if (collection.indexOf("users") > -1){ will process only collections with users in the name. It is **case sensitive**

Comment: yes i already mention my collection name there but i m not getting any result

Comment: yes it worked..now i want count for each collection ?

Comment: its printing all indexes instead of print indexes i want count for that indexes . eg. how many indexes are there in these collections??

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: thanku so much for your help..one more thing i can take CSV also for this ?

Comment: @NehaB Then you have to script your csv processing

Comment: can u  help me for this

Comment: Dunno depends on your OS, but could try ;-)

Comment: can we count documents for each collection in this case only ??

Comment: Taking CSV is the only problem?

Comment: Check out this [Stackoverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560393/bash-shell-scripting-csv-parsing) for some samples, insert your script and youre good to go!

Comment: How can i print Index Name also..?

Comment: want to print  "ns" name also..with count..? help me out?

Comment: Added a sample in my answer

Comment: thank you so much..may i know u know about python ,pandas??

Comment: Help me..If i want to match the condition and unset one parameter from my collection? How can i do?help me