# How to use awk to filter a .csv file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, echo, cat

I was wondering how can I get the names of the fruits in from this .csv file by using awk or some other cli tool.

I used a macro in vim to edit the file, but I would think that there is an easy one liner that would do the same.

[fruits.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/knadh/xmlutils.py/master/samples/fruits.csv):

```
"1000","Apple","4","133"
"1028","Lemon","3","120"
"1029","Lime","3","165"
"1030","Lychee","6","120"
"1031","Mango","6","131"
"1032","Mangostine","1","181"
"1033","Melon","4","159"
"1034","Cantaloupe","4","138"
"1035","Honeydew melon","4","155"
"1036","Watermelon","5","176"
"1037","Rock melon","2","180"
"1038","Nectarine","1","128"
"1039","Orange","6","142"
"1040","Peach","6","179"
"1041","Pear","3","102"
"1042","Williams pear or Bartlett pear","1","164"
"1043","Pitaya","2","170"
"1044","Physalis","5","166"
"1045","Plum/prune (dried plum)","4","103"
"1046","Pineapple","3","120"
"1047","Pomegranate","5","112"
"1048","Raisin","4","111"
"1049","Raspberry","5","156"
"1050","Western raspberry (blackcap)","6","173"
```

The final result that I would want would look like this:

```
Apple
Lemon
Lime
Lychee
Mango
Mangostine
Melon
Cantaloupe
Honeydew melon
Watermelon
Rock melon
Nectarine
Orange
Peach
Pear
Williams pear or Bartlett pear
Pitaya
Physalis
Plum/prune (dried plum)
Pineapple
Pomegranate
Raisin
Raspberry
Western raspberry (blackcap)
```

I realize that this is a duplicate:

[What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)

[How to parse a CSV in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560393/how-to-parse-a-csv-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: Using the presented duplicate, you quicly come too the answer : `awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '{print $2}' file.csv`

Comment: Here are some other methods too:
Method 1: `grep -o "[a-zA-Z() ]*" fruits.csv` to mach all desired characters,
Method 2: `cut -d"," -f2 fruits.csv | sed 's/"//g'` define a delimeter `-d","`, choose an index `-f2`, remove quotes with sed.
Method 3: `sed 's/[^,]*,//;s/,.*//;s/"//g' fruits.csv` remove everything up through the first comma, remove everything after and including the second comma, remove quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest:

```
awk -F '","' '{print $2}' file
```

Use `","` as field separator and output second column.

Answer (score 1):

Using combination of sed and awk

```
sed -e 's/^"//;s/","/\t/g;s/"//g' Input.csv| awk -F'\t' '{print$2}'
```

or

```
awk -F, '{print$2}' Input.csv | sed 's/"//g'
```

Both can print each column via changing the awk column number.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F',' -lane '$F[1] =~ tr/"//d; print $F[1];' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F','` : Split into `@F` on comma, rather than on whitespace.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk and `gensub()`:

```
$ gawk '{print gensub(/^[^,]*,"|([^,])".*/,"\\1","g")}' file
```

Output

```
Apple
...
Lemon
Lime
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` removing all `"` only in the second field and only at the begining and at the end of the second field.

```
awk -F',' '{gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$2);print $2}' file
Apple
Lemon
Lime
Lychee
Mango
Mangostine
Melon
Cantaloupe
Honeydew melon
Watermelon
Rock melon
Nectarine
Orange
Peach
Pear
Williams pear or Bartlett pear
Pitaya
Physalis
Plum/prune (dried plum)
Pineapple
Pomegranate
Raisin
Raspberry
Western raspberry (blackcap)
```